# Control touchable area in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a square `TouchableOpacity` button, whose graphics is just a small dot icon in the middle, and the rest is transparent background.
I find that in many Android devices it's quite difficult to press it, as apparently only the opaque area is touchable, and the rest isn't.

Is there any way then to control the touchable area of a `TouchableOpacity` or its other button-like siblings?

Comment: Can you add some of your views?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`View#hitSlop` property](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#hitslop) to increase the touchable area. This can be useful in scenarios where you know that the increased touch area won't overlap with other touchables.

A more robust solution is to use the `padding` style property. The touchable area of the `Touchable*` components includes the element's padding.

Comment: Good answer! By the way - does this means that `View#hitSlop` is also available for the `TouchableOpacity` component?

Comment: Yes, TouchableOpacity is also a View, so it inherits its properties.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Not as easy to find as you'd expect but I guess most people don't know to search for "hit slop".

Comment: Can you use hitSlop to click outside of the parent view boundary?

Comment: IIRC you can on iOS, not sure about Android right now. Give it a shot and report back!

Comment: @DrorBar I don't believe you can:

"** NOTE ** The touch area never extends past the parent view bounds and the Z-index of sibling views always takes precedence if a touch hits two overlapping views." 

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#hitslop

Answer (score 55):

I am just adding some code for easy referencing:

```
<View style={Styles.buttonStyle}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBtn1Pressed} hitSlop={{top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 50}}>
        <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>
           Button text
         </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Where the parent button container has the following style. Since the width is 150, I have given left and right as 50 to increase the clickable area.

```
 buttonStyle:{
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F92660',
    width:150,
    height:50,
    marginTop:20,
    marginBottom:10,
    marginRight:15,
    padding:5,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that my drawer icon was touchable from anywhere in the header. I solved the problem simply by adding a new view for the drawer icon and adding the icon with its properties in it.

**Before**

```
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" translucent={true} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.trigger}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          }}
        >
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={35} color={"grey"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**After**

```
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" translucent={true} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.trigger}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={35} color={"grey"} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the newly recommended [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component wrapper for buttons, you can use the prop called [hitSlop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#hitslop) to increase the pressable area.

Here is how you can use it

```
<Pressable
   onPress={() =>
   someFunction()}
   hitSlop={
   {
   left: 100, // To increase press area on the left side
   right: 100,// To increase press area on the right side
   bottom: undefined,
   top: undefined
   }}
   > 
   <Text>Press me </Text>
</Pressable>
```