# TouchableOpacity prevents click when margin added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing an app using expo and have a dynamically populated view to display info on basketball courts. Within this view is a fixed image and the content is displayed in a scrollable element with a top margin sufficient to display the image.

I am attempting to fix 2 touchableOpacity to the top of the scrollView overlaying the image.

[image: 2 btns on Single Court Page]

To achieve this I have a View which is placed within the ScrollView and justifyContent: 'space-between'

```js
<View
    style={{
        zIndex: 9,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        justifySelf: 'flex-start',
    }}
    >
        <BackBtn onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        <LikeBtn />
</View>
```

The right hand button works as expected, the left hand button works as expected if no margin is added or you press the margin to the left.

Expected Behaviour:

Right hand btn will handle A like feature

Left hand btn navigates back.

```js
<SafeAreaView>
            <View
                style={{
                    height: '100%',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    zIndex: -1,
                }}
            >
                <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/courtCard.jpg')}
                    resizeMode='cover'
                    style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: screen.height * 0.4,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            <View
                style={{
                    zIndex: 9,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    justifySelf: 'flex-start',
                }}
            >
                <BackBtn onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
                <LikeBtn />
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
                <View
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        minHeight: '60%',
                        height: 500,
                        marginTop: screen.height * 0.37,
                        zIndex: 1,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: '#f3f3f3',
                        borderTopStartRadius: 30,
                        borderTopEndRadius: 30,
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        paddingTop: 5,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name='minus' size={34} color='#b24747' />

                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Heading>{data.courtName || data?.attributes?.name}</Heading>

                        <Text
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: '#757575',
                                textAlign: 'center',
                                marginTop: 7,
                            }}
                        >
                            Submitted By: @
                            {data?.submittedBy?.username ||
                                data?.attributes?.submittedBy?.data?.attributes?.username}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            
        </SafeAreaView>
```

Things I have tried:

Adding padding to Button View and removing from Btn components
Adding Margin to Btn View
Positioning Btns Absolute (only right hand one works in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use hitslop to increase pressable area of ToucahbleOpacitiy. Explore this -> [Control touchable area in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955803/control-touchable-area-in-react-native)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not change the touchable area. However, it did work with the currently working "Like btn"

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue. There is a View in my header that is overflowing on top of the lefthand btn

[image]